VBA code for processing data in an Excel file crashes after processing about 400-500 rows
I have coded a VBA macro to process downloaded data. The data has some junk rows that need to be deleted, but also has some rows where the data is off by a couple of columns and a couple of rows. The macro moves data to the right place and deletes unnecessary rows.
It works well for about 400-500 rows and then it crashes.  The data I am trying to process is about 900-1,000 rows.
Here is an example of a few rows of the raw data:



Team 1 Batters






















Schedule

Rankings

Trends

Contracts



Stats






Pos
Players
13-May
5/14- 5/21
Proj
Actual
Rost
Start
Salary
Contract
*
EXT
BA
R
HR
RBI
SB


C
Patrick Bailey C  SF


213
195
0.17
0.05
5
E-2025


0.28
10
3
11
1


Not in Lineup



















LAD,  9:45pm ETvs TBA
Home: 5 (LAD,COL)Away: 1 (@PIT)
213
195
17%
5%
5
E-2025


0.281
10
3
11
1



C
Keibert Ruiz C  WAS


104
487
0.27
0.14
5
E-2025
**
X
0.15
5
2
6
0


Game Postponed



















No Game
Home: 2 (MIN)Away: 6 (@CHW,@PHI)
104
487
27%
14%
5
E-2025
**
X
0.147
5
2
6
0



1B
Christian Walker 1B  ARI


41
32
1
0.98
30
E-2025
**

0.26
30
8
28
1


Batting 4th



















CIN,  9:40pm ETvs TBA
Home: 5 (CIN,DET)Away: 2 (@LAD)
41
32
100%
98%
30
E-2025
**

0.255
30
8
28
1



2B
Kevin Newman 2B,3B,SS  ARI
CIN,  9:40pm ETvs TBA
Home: 5 (CIN,DET)Away: 2 (@LAD)
N/A
247
2%
1%
10
E-2026


0.253
12
2
10
0



Batting 9th

















3B
Patrick Wisdom 1B,3B,OF  CHC
@ATL,  7:20pm ETvs TBA
Home: 5 (PIT,ATL)Away: 2 (@ATL)
275
246
11%
5%
7
E-2026


0.289
5
2
7
3



Not in Lineup

















SS
Ketel Marte 2B,SS  ARI
CIN,  9:40pm ETvs TBA
Home: 5 (CIN,DET)Away: 2 (@LAD)
46
17
100%
99%
27
E-2025


0.287
31
9
25
1



Batting 2nd

















MI
Ozzie Albies 2B  ATL


16
85
1
0.97
31
E-2025
**

0.28
21
3
19
2


Batting 2nd



















CHC,  7:20pm ETvs TBA
Home: 6 (CHC,SD)Away: 1 (@CHC)
16
85
100%
97%
31
E-2025
**

0.279
21
3
19
2



CI
Freddie Freeman 1B  LAD


5
41
1
1
36
E-2024
**

0.3
29
4
25
1


Batting 3rd



















@SF,  9:45pm ETvs TBA
Home: 6 (CIN,ARI)Away: 2 (@SF)
5
41
100%
100%
36
E-2024
**

0.295
29
4
25
1



OF
Harrison Bader OF  NYM


200
135
0.14
0.09
6
E-2026


0.27
16
1
10
6


Batting 7th



















PHI,  7:10pm ETvs TBA
Home: 1 (PHI)Away: 7 (@PHI,@MIA,@CLE)
200
135
14%
9%
6
E-2026


0.273
16
1
10
6



OF
Brenton Doyle OF  COL


188
33
0.64
0.48
7
E-2026


0.27
29
5
13
9


Batting 6th



















@SD,  9:40pm ETvs TBA
Home: 0 Away: 6 (@SD,@SF,@OAK)
188
33
64%
48%
7
E-2026


0.273
29
5
13
9



OF
Jake Fraley OF  CIN


136
126
0.39
0.24
8
E-2024


0.29
17
1
7
7


Not in Lineup



















@ARI,  9:40pm ETvs TBA
Home: 1 (SD)Away: 6 (@ARI,@LAD)
136
126
39%
24%
8
E-2024


0.286
17
1
7
7



OF
Blake Perkins OF  MIL


325
148
0.11
0.06
10
E-2026


0.21
20
4
14
3


Not in Lineup



















PIT,  7:40pm ETvs TBA
Home: 2 (PIT)Away: 5 (@HOU,@MIA)
325
148
11%
6%
10
E-2026


0.214
20
4
14
3



OF
Seiya Suzuki OF  CHC


54
133
0.98
0.86
20
E-2025


0.27
16
4
15
1


Batting 2nd



















@ATL,  7:20pm ETvs TBA
Home: 5 (PIT,ATL)Away: 2 (@ATL)
54
133
98%
86%
20
E-2025


0.27
16
4
15
1



U
Luis Matos OF  SF


259
210
0.31
0.2
5
E-2025


0.39
4
2
17
0


Batting 8th



















LAD,  9:45pm ETvs TBA
Home: 5 (LAD,COL)Away: 1 (@PIT)
259
210
31%
20%
5
E-2025


0.385
4
2
17
0



Injured


















OF
Nolan Jones OF  COL


27
344
0.82
0.08
10
E-2025


0.17
11
1
7
2


Not in Lineup



















@SD,  9:40pm ETvs TBA
Home: 0 Away: 6 (@SD,@SF,@OAK)
27
344
82%
8%
10
E-2025


0.17
11
1
7
2



Minors


















2B
Eguy Rosario 2B,3B  SD
COL,  9:40pm ETvs TBA
Home: 2 (COL)Away: 5 (@ATL,@CIN)
304
311
2%
0%
1
E-2026


0.25
4
3
6
0


3B
Cam Collier 3B  CIN
@ARI,  9:40pm ETvs TBA
Home: 1 (SD)Away: 6 (@ARI,@LAD)
N/A
N/A
7%
0%
5
E-2026


0
0
0
0
0


3B
Kody Hoese 3B  LAD
@SF,  9:45pm ETvs TBA
Home: 6 (CIN,ARI)Away: 2 (@SF)
N/A
N/A
1%
0%
5
E-2026


0
0
0
0
0


SS
Aidan Miller SS  PHI
@NYM,  7:10pm ETvs TBA
Home: 6 (NYM,WAS,TEX)Away: 1 (@NYM)
N/A
N/A
7%
0%
5
E-2026


0
0
0
0
0


OF
Owen Caissie OF  CHC
@ATL,  7:20pm ETvs TBA
Home: 5 (PIT,ATL)Away: 2 (@ATL)
N/A
N/A
9%
0%
5
E-2026


0
0
0
0
0


OF
Alexander Ramirez OF  NYM
PHI,  7:10pm ETvs TBA
Home: 1 (PHI)Away: 7 (@PHI,@MIA,@CLE)
N/A
N/A
2%
0%
5
E-2026


0
0
0
0
0


U
Tyler Black 1B,3B  MIL
PIT,  7:40pm ETvs TBA
Home: 2 (PIT)Away: 5 (@HOU,@MIA)
N/A
431
17%
0%
5
E-2026


0.227
1
0
0
2


U
Mark Vientos 3B  NYM


N/A
354
0.06
0.02
5
E-2025


0.33
3
1
4
0


Not in Lineup



















PHI,  7:10pm ETvs TBA
Home: 1 (PHI)Away: 7 (@PHI,@MIA,@CLE)
N/A
354
6%
2%
5
E-2025


0.333
3
1
4
0



Team 1 Pitchers




















Schedule

Rankings

Trends

Contracts



Stats






Pos
Players
13-May
5/14- 5/21
Proj
Actual
Rost
Start
Salary
Contract
*
EXT
ERA
WHIP
W
K
S


P
Kyle Harrison P  SF
LAD,  9:45pm ET
Home: 5 (LAD,COL)Away: 1 (@PIT)
126
74
86%
48%
5
E-2026


3.6
1.27
4
49
0


P
A.J. Minter P  ATL
CHC,  7:20pm ET
Home: 6 (CHC,SD)Away: 1 (@CHC)
236
75
32%
24%
8
E-2026


3.57
1.02
5
20
1


P
Hector Neris P  CHC
@ATL,  7:20pm ET
Home: 5 (PIT,ATL)Away: 2 (@ATL)
225
93
56%
47%
5
E-2026


2.65
1.65
4
15
6


P
Mitchell Parker P  WAS
No Game
Home: 2 (MIN)Away: 6 (@CHW,@PHI)
N/A
157
33%
18%
10
E-2026


3.09
1.12
2
25
0



Here is the desired output:



Team 1 Batters





















Schedule

Rankings

Trends

Contracts



Stats





Pos
Players
13-May
5/14- 5/21
Proj
Actual
Rost
Start
Salary
Contract
*
EXT
BA
R
HR
RBI


C
Patrick Bailey C  SF


213
195
0.18
0.07
5
E-2025


0.281
10
3
11


C
Keibert Ruiz C  WAS


104
489
0.28
0.13
5
E-2025
**
X
0.147
5
2
6


1B
Christian Walker 1B  ARI


41
30
1
0.98
30
E-2025
**

0.259
30
8
28


2B
Kevin Newman 2B,3B,SS  ARI
CIN,  9:40pm ETvs TBA
Home: 5 (CIN,DET)Away: 2 (@LAD)
N/A
239
1%
1%
10
E-2026


0.253
12
2
10


3B
Patrick Wisdom 1B,3B,OF  CHC
@ATL,  7:20pm ETvs TBA
Home: 5 (PIT,ATL)Away: 2 (@ATL)
275
238
11%
6%
7
E-2026


0.294
5
2
7


SS
Ketel Marte 2B,SS  ARI
CIN,  9:40pm ETvs TBA
Home: 5 (CIN,DET)Away: 2 (@LAD)
46
20
100%
99%
27
E-2025


0.288
30
9
24


MI
Ozzie Albies 2B  ATL


16
84
1
0.97
31
E-2025
**

0.279
21
3
19



Here is the code:
Option Explicit

Public Function ContainsArrayValue(StringToCheck As String, ValuesToLookFor As Variant) As Boolean
    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(ValuesToLookFor) To UBound(ValuesToLookFor)
        If InStr(1, StringToCheck, ValuesToLookFor(i)) > 0 Then
            ContainsArrayValue = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next i
    ContainsArrayValue = False
End Function

Public Function IsInArray(StringToBeFound As String, ValuesToCheck As Variant) As Boolean
    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(ValuesToCheck) To UBound(ValuesToCheck)
        If ValuesToCheck(i) = StringToBeFound Then
            IsInArray = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next i
    IsInArray = False
End Function

Public Function IsDivisible(x As Integer, d As Integer) As Boolean
    IsDivisible = (x Mod d) = 0
End Function

Sub CleanUpTwoLines(ReferenceRow As Range)
    Dim i As Long
    Dim TargetRange As Range
    Dim SourceRange As Range
    Dim TargetRow1 As Range
    Dim TargetRow2 As Range

    Set TargetRange = Range(ReferenceRow.Cells(1, 5), ReferenceRow.Cells(1, 17))
    Set SourceRange = TargetRange.Offset(2, -1)
    
    For i = 1 To 13
        TargetRange.Cells(1, i).Value = SourceRange.Cells(1, i)
    Next i

    Set TargetRow1 = ReferenceRow.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow
    Set TargetRow2 = ReferenceRow.Offset(2, 0).EntireRow
    
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    TargetRow1.Delete
    TargetRow2.Delete
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Sub CleanUpOneLine(ReferenceRow As Range)
    Dim TargetRow1 As Range
    Set TargetRow1 = ReferenceRow.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow
    
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    TargetRow1.Delete
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Sub PlayerRowCleanup(PlayerRow As Range, PlayerPosValues As Variant)
    If IsInArray(PlayerRow.Cells(1, 1).Offset(2, 0).Value, PlayerPosValues) = False Then                                    'We already know the line below is not a player; if the line two rows below is also not a player...
        Call CleanUpTwoLines(PlayerRow)                                                                                                         'Then do the two-line cleanup, which involves moving stats and deleting those two rows
    Else                                                                                                                                                            'If it's in fact just one row that's not a player...
        Call CleanUpOneLine(PlayerRow)                                                                                                           'Then delete that row
    End If
    
    While IsInArray(PlayerRow.Cells(1, 1).Offset(1, 0).Value, PlayerPosValues) = False                                     'Check if there are any extra non-player rows...
        PlayerRow.Cells(1, 1).Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Delete                                                                               'If so delete them
    Wend
End Sub

Sub CleanUpAllRosterData()
    Dim JunkRowValues() As String
    Dim PlayerPosValues() As String
    Dim a As Range, b As Range
    Dim RowsToDelete As Range
    Dim counter As Integer

    JunkRowValues = Split("Batters,Pitchers,Minors,Injured,Pos,pitchers,Schedule,Not In Lineup", ",")
    PlayerPosValues = Split("C,1B,2B,SS,3B,MI,CI,OF,U,P", ",")
    
    Set a = Range("AllTeamsData")
    a.Cells.UnMerge
    counter = 0
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    
    For Each b In a.Rows
        counter = counter + 1
        If IsDivisible(counter, 20) Then
            If MsgBox("Analyzing row " & b.Row & " processed " & counter & " rows. Continue?", vbYesNo) = vbNo Then
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
        
        If ContainsArrayValue(b.Cells(1, 1).Value, JunkRowValues) Then                                                        'Check whether the current row is junk
            If RowsToDelete Is Nothing Then                                                                                                  'If it is delete it
                Set RowsToDelete = b.EntireRow
            Else
                Set RowsToDelete = Union(RowsToDelete, b.EntireRow)
            End If
        ElseIf IsInArray(b.Cells(1, 1).Value, PlayerPosValues) Then                                                                 'Check whether the current row is a player row
            If Not IsInArray(b.Cells(1, 1).Offset(1, 0).Value, PlayerPosValues) Then                                         'If the next line is also a player row, then no need to do anything--go to the next row
                Call PlayerRowCleanup(b, PlayerPosValues)                                                                                'If the next line is not also a player row, then call for cleanup
            End If
        End If
    Next b
    
    If Not RowsToDelete Is Nothing Then
        RowsToDelete.Delete
    End If
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub


I would greatly appreciate any thoughts on what is causing the crash after the first 400-500 rows.
I have run the code through ChatGPT and followed its suggestions.  The macro still crashes.

Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?.
Please create MD table with online tool Table Generator What's your expected output?

What do you mean with crash excatly? Do you mean that excel will just end without any error message and you have to restart it?

I suspect that collecting all the rows you would like to delete with Set RowsToDelete = Union(RowsToDelete, b.EntireRow) might be the reason for the issuse. I would suggest to replace that with a different approach.

One method suggested on here when deleting rows is to start from the last row and head to the first. Apparently the reason is because the data is put into memory and does not like renumbering the rows every time one gets deleted...

What's your expected output?

Yes, “crash” here means both Excel and the VBA window become completely unresponsive.  For a few second there’s a message at the bottom of the Excel window mentioning “threads” and showing a percentage.  Then that goes away and it’s completely frozen.  This is on Excel for Mac.

Collecting rows for deletion at the end was actually something ChatGPT suggested. I was having the same issue before that change.  I don’t THINK it’s making a difference one way or the other.

I’ll post the expected output later but basically it should look like a normal baseball team roster.

@czw you could capture row numbers in an array instead of in a range. Then loop through the array to delete rows from end to beginning.

Doubt the problem is collecting rows and deleting them all at once, this data set seems small enough. For debugging - Don't turn off Application.ScreenUpdating- you want to be able to see what's happening / how far it is getting so you can figure out where it is hanging. Add some breakpoints or stops to break up your code and isolate which line is causing it to hang.


There is an infinite loop in PlayerRowCleanup. It leads to crash (Excel no response).

Note:

The data of the last player (Ozzie Albies) in the source table is incomplete. So it isn't in the output.
There are missing data in your expected output table, highlighted in green in my screenshot.

Microsoft documentation:

InStr function


Range.Resize property (Excel)


Range.AutoFit method (Excel)

Option Explicit
Sub Demo()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim arrData, rngData As Range, sErrList As String
    Dim arrRes, iR As Long, iMode As Long
    Dim oSht As Worksheet, RowCnt As Long
     ' modify as needed, the 1st and last char should be "|"
    Const POS = "|C|1B|2B|SS|3B|MI|CI|OF|U|P|"
    Const SKIP_ROWS = 3
    Set oSht = Sheets("Data") ' modify as needed
    ' load data into an array
    arrData = oSht.UsedRange.Value
    arrRes = arrData
    RowCnt = UBound(arrData)
    iR = SKIP_ROWS
    ' loop through data
    For i = LBound(arrData) + SKIP_ROWS To RowCnt
        If Len(arrData(i, 1)) > 0 And InStr(1, POS, "|" & arrData(i, 1) & "|", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            ' get the row count for each player
            If RowCnt - i < 3 Then
                iMode = RowCnt - i + 1
            ElseIf InStr(1, POS, "|" & arrData(i + 3, 1) & "|", vbTextCompare) Then
                iMode = 3
            ElseIf InStr(1, POS, "|" & arrData(i + 2, 1) & "|", vbTextCompare) Then
                iMode = 2
            Else
                iMode = 0
            End If
            Select Case iMode
            Case 0 ' missing data
                sErrList = sErrList & "," & arrData(i, 1)
            Case 2 ' two rows
                iR = iR + 1
                For j = LBound(arrData, 2) To UBound(arrData, 2)
                    arrRes(iR, j) = arrData(i, j)
                Next j
                i = i + 1
            Case 3 ' three rows
                iR = iR + 1
                For j = LBound(arrData, 2) To UBound(arrData, 2)
                    If j < 3 Then
                        arrRes(iR, j) = arrData(i, j)
                    Else
                        arrRes(iR, j) = arrData(i + 2, j - 1)
                    End If
                Next j
                i = i + 2
            End Select
        End If
    Next i
    ' write output to sheet
    Sheets.Add
    Range("A2").Resize(iR, UBound(arrData, 2)).Value = arrRes
    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Columns(1).ColumnWidth = 4
    If Len(sErrList) > 0 Then
        MsgBox "Missing data for:" & vbCr & Mid(sErrList, 2)
    Else
        MsgBox "Done"
    End If
End Sub



Update:
Option Explicit
Sub Demo()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim arrData, rngData As Range, sErrList As String
    Dim arrRes, iR As Long, iMode As Long, iNext As Long
    Dim oSht As Worksheet, RowCnt As Long, bHeader As Boolean
     ' modify as needed, the 1st and last char should be "|"
    Const POS = "|C|1B|2B|SS|3B|MI|CI|OF|U|P|"
    Const SKIP_ROWS = 3
    Set oSht = Sheets("Data") ' modify as needed
    ' load data into an array
    arrData = oSht.UsedRange.Value
    arrRes = arrData
    RowCnt = UBound(arrData)
    iR = SKIP_ROWS
    ' loop through data
    For i = LBound(arrData) + SKIP_ROWS To RowCnt
        If Len(arrData(i, 1)) > 0 And InStr(1, POS, "|" & arrData(i, 1) & "|", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            ' locate the next player
            iMode = 0: iNext = 0: bHeader = False
            For j = i + 1 To RowCnt
                If InStr(1, POS, "|" & arrData(j, 1) & "|", vbTextCompare) Then
                    iNext = j ' start row# of next player
                    Exit For
                ElseIf UCase(Left(arrData(j, 1), 4)) = "TEAM" Then
                    bHeader = True ' extra header
                End If
            Next
            ' get the row count for each player
            If iNext > 0 Then
                iMode = iNext - i
                If bHeader Then iMode = iMode - SKIP_ROWS
            Else
                If RowCnt - i < 3 Then
                    iMode = RowCnt - i + 1
                End If
            End If
            Select Case iMode
            Case 0 ' missing data
                sErrList = sErrList & "," & arrData(i, 2)
            Case 1, 2 ' two rows
                iR = iR + 1
                For j = LBound(arrData, 2) To UBound(arrData, 2)
                    arrRes(iR, j) = arrData(i, j)
                Next j
                i = i + (iMode - 1)
            Case 3, 4 ' three rows
                iR = iR + 1
                For j = LBound(arrData, 2) To UBound(arrData, 2)
                    If j < 3 Then
                        arrRes(iR, j) = arrData(i, j)
                    Else
                        arrRes(iR, j) = arrData(i + 2, j - 1)
                    End If
                Next j
                i = i + 2
            End Select
            If bHeader Then i = i + SKIP_ROWS ' skip extra header
        End If
    Next i
    ' write output to sheet
    Sheets.Add
    Range("A2").Resize(iR, UBound(arrData, 2)).Value = arrRes
    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Columns(1).ColumnWidth = 4
    If Len(sErrList) > 0 Then
        MsgBox "Missing data for:" & vbCr & Mid(sErrList, 2)
    Else
        MsgBox "Done"
    End If
End Sub



Wow taller, this is amazing.  One thing (I pasted in additional rows above): There are player rows that have 3 or more rows of "junk" after them (see Matos and Vientos) and player rows that have no junk after them--i.e. they are followed by another player. I don't think your macro is handling those correctly.
I probably should have pasted in more initially; I'll work through your code to figure out how to tweak it. That will take a little while because it has some functions that are new to me. Any words of advice on how to go about it would be super-helpful.
But anyway, thanks VERY much.

As to the "missing data" in columns C and D: those columns aren't important to me.  I'll be deleting them in the final code.

One last thing: I think you're totally right about the endless loop in PlayerRowCleanup.  I think my code was getting to the end and then getting stuck in PlayerRowCleanup at that point.  This would explain why it was crashing after processing half the rows--it was in fact done.  (The code often deleted 1 or 2 rows below the row being processed, so it could get through 1,000 rows while only processing about half that.)
One important takeaway here: When debugging, consider that your code WORKS, but has gotten to the end and you didn't plan for what should happen then.

There are player rows that have 3 or more rows of "junk" after them (see Matos and Vientos) and player rows that have no junk after them -- The code doesn’t handle both scenarios because they don’t appear in your sample table before the update. Do you want to keep the 2nd table header section ( 3 rows starts at Team 1 Pitchers)?

I've updated the code and tested it with your new sample data.
